# How to change Flash players setting to allow browser list the files from local folder?

Tags: actionscript-3, flexbuilder

I need to list the files under a local folder on web browser(flex app).
How do i change the properties of flash player so that it will browser list the files?
Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use FileReference.
However, in a web browser you are locked into only using this function if there is user interaction( IE:a mouse click ).
Anything over then this would be a major security risk and Flash player will not allow it.
There is nothing that can be done about this.

With that being said if you can do without a browser you can access it through an Air app without having to deal with the security issues.

Answer (score 0):

The flash player in a browser does not have the ability to browse the files on a server. You will need to use server-side scripting, such as PHP, to make this data avaiable.

The file browser in flash player just browses the users local hard drive.

Comment: can i create a actionscript by using classes like FileReferenceList.browse() method to browse the folder and FileReferenceList.FileList() method list the files under that folder?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question 100% right. Are the files you want to browse on the users hard drive, or are they on the server?

Comment: The folder that i want browse is on my local machine(local hard drive)

Comment: OK, I misunderstood. In that case the comment by the_asMan seems to be correct: use FileReference. And as he mentions, the browse must be triggered by a user initiated mouse event.

Comment: you mean something like this?              fr = new FileReferenceList();
   fr.browse([new FileFilter("Zip Files", "*.zip")]);
   fr.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, listZipFiles);

Comment: Use FileReference for getting a list of files the user selected to upload. And FileReference when saving a file.

Comment: I just caught this: Should say, "Use Use FileReferenceList for getting a list of files the user selected to upload. And FileReference when saving a file."

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code:

```
// ActionScript file

   import flash.display.*;
   import flash.events.*;
   import flash.net.FileFilter;
   import flash.net.FileReference;
   import flash.net.FileReferenceList;
   import flash.utils.ByteArray;    
   import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
   import mx.controls.Alert;

    private var fr:FileReferenceList;
    [Bindable] private var zfls:Array;
    [Bindable] private var zfile:FileReference;
    [Bindable] private var zipfl:ArrayCollection;

    private function folder():void
    {
        fr = new FileReferenceList();
        fr.browse([new FileFilter("Zip Files", "*.zip")]);
        fr.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, listZipFiles);            
    }

    private function listZipFiles(event:Event):void
    {
        Alert.show("selectHandler: " + fr.fileList.length + " files");          
        zfile = new FileReference();
        zfls = new Array();  

        for (var i:uint = 0; i < fr.fileList.length; i++) 
        {
            zfile = FileReference(fr.fileList[i]);
            //Alert.show("Length of zfile is " + zfile.size);
            zfls.push(zfile);                                                   
        }
        //Alert.show("Is the File comming in?" + zfls);
        zipfl = new ArrayCollection(zfls);
        //Alert.show("Length of zipfl is" +zipfl);          
    }
```

and then i m binding zipfl to a comboBox.